# How can I download the source code of kernel 3.5.0-17-generic image shipped with Ubuntu-12.10

Tags: 12.10, kernel, source-code, source

Where can I get the exact source code of linux kernel version 3.5.0-17-generic which is shipped with Ubuntu 12.10 ?

Comment: 12.10 went end of life and so the software got moved to archives. We only support questing regarding current releases. The kernel source code from the Ubuntu repositories through "apt-get" is no longer available. You can find old releases here: http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/ but will have to manually download the files.

Comment: @Rinzwind on the link http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/quantal/ I dont see anything that looks like a kernel source, which files to download then ?

Answer (score 1):

If you are looking to just get the sources to the kernel that you are currently running you can:

```
apt-get source linux-image-$(uname -r)
```

source code for all ubuntu releases `http://kernel.ubuntu.com/git/`

Please check this `https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/3.5.0-17.28` the source code and the patches are available here available here. If you want generic source code then better look for it on `kernel.org`.

Comment: Either he is running 12.10 and `apt-get` will error out (12.10 is EOL) or he will get either 12.04, 14.04 or 15.04 and that is not what he is asking. The last bit is a way to go though :)